# Interview - bit operations

Tags: c, algorithm, bit

I was asked to implement `invert(x,p,n)` that returns x with the n bits that begin at
position p inverted (i.e., 1 changed into 0 and vice versa), leaving the others unchanged.

My solution is:

```
unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)
{
       return (x ^ (((1 << (n + 1)) - 1) << (p - n + 1)));
}
```

I found on net this solution for the problem :

```
unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n)
{
    return x ^ ((~(~0<<n))<< p+1-n);
}
```

For me it looks incorrect - What is the correct and effective approach for the problem

Comment: Does it give the right result? Does yours?

Comment: position is from lsb or msb?

Comment: What tells you the code is incorrect ? Can you prove it with results ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your implementation is clearly incorrect; consider `p = 1, n = 2`:

```
x ^ (((1 << (n + 1)) - 1) << (p - n + 1))
x ^ (((1 << 3) - 1) << 0)
x ^ ((8 - 1) << 0)
x ^ 7
```

This inverts the three low-order bits of x, not two.  We can fix that by instead using:

```
return x ^ (1 << n) - 1 << p - n + 1;
```

(I got rid of the copious spurious parentheses as well).  This still has a corner-case bug; if the caller wants to flip all but one of the bits (i.e. `n == sizeof x * CHAR_BIT - 1`).  Let’s assume that int is 32 bits and work an example:

```
x ^ (1 << n) - 1 << p - n + 1;
x ^ (1 << 31) - 1 << p - 31 + 1;
    ^^^^^^^^^
    ruh-roh!
```

Unfortunately, this invokes undefined behavior (C11, §6.5.7 paragraph 4):

> If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

You can fix *this* by making the constant `1` unsigned ...

```
return x ^ (1U << n) - 1 << p - n + 1;
```

... but then you *still* have undefined behavior when `n == sizeof x * CHAR_BIT` (i.e. if the caller wants to flip *all* the bits) (C11, §6.5.7 paragraph 3):

> If the value of the right operand ... is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

The solution that you found on the net suffers from undefined behavior in the same manner.  If you really want to get all the edge cases obsessively pedantically correct, you’ll need to do something along these lines:

```
unsigned invert(unsigned x, int p, int n) {
    if (p < 0 || p >= sizeof x * CHAR_BIT) {
        /* flip out and kill people */
    }
    if (n < 0 || n > p + 1) {
        /*  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻) */
    }
    if (n == sizeof x * CHAR_BIT) return ~x;
    /* Having dealt with all the undefined cases,
       we can safely use your nice expression.
       But without all the parentheses.  Superfluous
       parentheses make hulk angry. */
    return x ^ (1U << n) - 1 << p - n + 1;
}
```

Is this pedantic overkill?  Yes.  Would I expect someone to write this as a first pass in an interview situation?  No.  Would I want them to be able to intelligently discuss the hazards involved here?  Yes.

Comment: +1 for the "intelligently discuss".  (Actually +1 for "make hulk angry")

Comment: your  solution lacks the check n + p >== sizeof (unsigned)

Comment: `n + p >= sizeof x * CHAR_BIT` (what I think you actually mean) isn’t a needed check based on your description of the problem — the problem statement is to flip bits `p:p-n+1`, so there’s no need to have a check on `n + p`.

Comment: You're hired! But seriously, that paragraph never copy-and-pastes well.

Comment: @StephenCanon - no.the problem definition states "n bits that begin at position p inverted".i.e. if we can`t revert n bits we don`t solve the problem

Comment: @Yakov: based on the two draft solutions in the question, the highest-order bit to be flipped is bit `p`.  `n` bits total are to be flipped.  This does not create a constraint on `p + n`.  Instead it creates the constraint `p - n + 1 >= 0` (you can’t flip a bit with a lower index than `0`).  That constraint is enforced in my example by the second term of the second `if` statement.